# How does Mongodb $pull work under the hood

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Imagine the following two documents in a `myCollection`:

`{_id: '1', fruits: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon']}`

`{_id: '1', fruits: ['Apple', 'Lemon']}`

Is there a difference of performance between:

`db.myCollection.update({}, {$pull: 'Banana'}, {multi: true)}`

and:

`db.myCollection.update({fruits: {$elemMatch: 'Banana'}}, {$pull: 'Banana'}, {multi: true)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
//output from mongo client
//ran below queries and compared the output from explain. I did not find any difference in //execution stats for performance
> db.myCollection.explain("executionStats").update(
...    {},
...    {$pull:{fruits:{$in:["Banana"]}}},
...    {multi: true}
...    );
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.myCollection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {

                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "UPDATE",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                                "direction" : "forward"
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 2,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "UPDATE",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 4,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 3,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "nMatched" : 2,
                        "nWouldModify" : 2,
                        "wouldInsert" : false,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 2,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 4,
                                "advanced" : 2,
                                "needTime" : 1,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 2,
                                "restoreState" : 2,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "docsExamined" : 2
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "XXXX",
                "port" : XXXX,
                "version" : "4.2.6",
                "gitVersion" : "XXXX"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
>
--
> db.myCollection.explain("executionStats").update(
...   {},
...   {$pull:
...       {fruits:{$elemMatch:{$in:["Banana"]}}}
...   },
...   {multi: true}
... );
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.myCollection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {

                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "UPDATE",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                                "direction" : "forward"
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 2,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "UPDATE",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 4,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 3,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "nMatched" : 2,
                        "nWouldModify" : 2,
                        "wouldInsert" : false,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 2,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 4,
                                "advanced" : 2,
                                "needTime" : 1,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 2,
                                "restoreState" : 2,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "docsExamined" : 2
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "XXXX",
                "port" : XXX,
                "version" : "4.2.6",
                "gitVersion" : "XXXX"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
>
```

Comment: I think you have the same query for both.